# Explanation needed for a syntax in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and after learning some topics i wanted to do a small project (an email sender).When i was researching a bit about libraries needed and some examples, I saw the following piece of code :

```
msg['Subject'] = 'The contents of %s' % textfile
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you
```

I am confused about the syntax:

```
var['something'] = anything
```

What does this syntax imply? Please help.

Comment: in addition to @rfj001's answer, [this link](http://sthurlow.com/python/lesson06/) has a nice concise explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sort of syntax is used for accessing/modifying Python [dictionaries](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm). The  example `var["Something"] = anything` is setting the value of the variable `anything` in the dictionary `var` for the key `"Something"`

Keys must be immutable objects, such as strings, integers, floating-point numbers, or tuples.
Dictionary values can be any python object.

Comment: msg = MIMEText(fp.read())
this code was used to take the string.How is that 'msg' acting as a dictionary now?

Comment: The `MIMEText(fp.read())` function has a dictionary as a return value. The dictionary generated is formatted to be sent as an email. The value for the `"Subject"` key specifies the subject of the email, the value for the `"From"` key specifies the sender email address, and the value for the `"To"` key specifies the email addresses to send the message to. The body of the email would contain the contents of the file pointed to by the file pointer `fp`.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is used for python data structure dictionary which much like telephone dictionary enables us to associate a keyword (in square brackets) with a value (on LHS). For more details, please refer to section 5.5 in tutorial https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html